# Is it possible to have two declarations of C++ class depending on its use?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to have two declarations of C++ class depending on its use?
In practice, this would mean two header files for the class.
Should this work in the current compilers? Does it work?

One class has the class defined (a cpp file) but has different declarations(.h) which are used in different files, (the included in the header files )are different.

Answer (score 3):

Two classes with the same name but a different body? That is explicitly disallowed and will lead to all sorts of strange errors. Don't do it.

Comment: you do not seem to understand the question

Comment: Well, go ahead and clarify it then.

Answer (score 0):

No, you're not allowed to do this, at all. (It is "undefined behaviour", and it does not even require a diagnostic.)